# Should we delclare/define destructor even if the class is composed by only smart pointers?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
class A{
   public:
       A():p(nullptr){};
   private:
       std::unique_ptr<B> p;  // B is some class
 };
```

When the object of A goes out of scope, the memory space which consumes for **p** is automatically removed.

Should we explicitly write the destructor as below?

```
~A(){
      delete p;
}
```

Is this redundant?

Comment: `ptr` is undeclared.  If you meant `p`, `p` is not a raw pointer.

Comment: I debugged it:-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we explicitly write the destructor as below?

No. The whole point of smart pointers is that memory is managed automatically for you.

> Is this redundant?

No, it's **undefined behavior** - a *"double free"* will be performed. Even if you provide a destructor for `A`, `p`'s destructor will be called regardless.